# Change WooCommerce invoice order mail recipient

Tags: email, woocommerce, invoice

I've set up a Woocommerce webshop and would like to change the recipient for the order invoice.

The website uses WooCommerce V3.6.5 with the Flatsome Theme.

I tried to change the admin email address in Wordpress settings but that didn't work. I still receive the invoice at the old email address.

I tried to look into the function.php but that only shows the following:

```
 * @package flatsome
 */

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/init.php';
```

Does anyone know how to change the order invoice recipient? In the WooCommerce -> Settings -> Email tab I can only change the email formats and "From" email address.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this solution using `$recipient` variable, please have a try.

```
function change_email_recipient( $recipient ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $recipient = 'email@email.com';
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'change_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```